# Setting encoding for new projects in PhpStorm

Tags: php, encoding, phpstorm, file-encodings

I am trying to force PhpStorm to encode newly created files as UTF-8, instead of  Windows-1252 (which seems to be the default).

I know I can set "Project encoding" in "settings/editor/file encodings", which sets the default encoding for all newly created files **in the current project**.

However I'd like to set default encoding for **new projects**, so I will not have to change it every time I create a new project. I've searched far and wide on the internets, but with no success.

**Do you guys know how to set file encoding for new projects?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The IDE uses the default of the underlying operation system. And indeed many installations of MS-Windows still use totally outdated 8-bit encodings (like Windows-1252, which is close to ISO-latin1). Check if ou can switch the operating systems settings, so your file systems default encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All available settings that are *used as defaults for newly created projects* can be set at **`File | Default Settings...`**.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/accessing-default-settings.html

You can also access them directly from *Welcome screen* -- will be just `Settings` under `Configure` drop down (could be called `Preferences` on Mac -- cannot verify that as I have no Mac). But in this case default settings will be mixed with IDE-wide settings as well.

In both cases the options you need to change will be under `Editor | File Encodings`.

Comment: I have to try it out, but it seems this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of trouble. (I always remember to set it to UTF-8 only after some file gets messed up by the wrong encoding :D )

Comment: It works -- I did set it up few years ago and still got UTF-8 in all new projects.

Answer (score 2):

When creating new projects, you can set a proper IDE Encoding, its right next to the Project Encoding:

[image: File Encodings PHPStorm]

When you edit an existing project, it automatically recognizes the current encoding and offers you to convert/reload the project in a proper encoding.

Comment: I have IDE Encoding set to UTF-8, but whenever I create a new project, it is always created with Project Encoding - Windows 1252